Why does Folly's `rcu_domain.retire(list_node* node)` require non-blocking `half_sync`?
I've been examining Folly's implementation of RCU.h, particularly how half_sync is used within the retire function. The relevant snippet is shown as follows:
void retire(list_node* node) noexcept {
 // ...
 if (...) {
   list_head finished;
   {
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(syncMutex_);
     half_sync(false, finished);
   }
   // ...
 }
}

void half_sync(bool blocking, list_head& finished) {
  auto curr = version_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
  auto next = curr + 1;
    
  // ...
  if (blocking) {
    counters_.waitForZero(next & 1);
  } else {
    if (!counters_.epochIsClear(next & 1)) {
      return;
    }
  }
  // ...
}

From my understanding, half_sync waits or checks (depending on blocking) for all read-side critical sections to move to the current epoch and then increments the version_, performing memory reclamation on items retired two epochs ago (by adding the items in the finished pointer, allowing the reclamation to begin from other functions).
The retire function calls half_sync(false) (non-blocking), but the comments suggest that using half_sync(true) (blocking) might cause a deadlock:

Note that it's likely we hold a read lock here, so we can only half_sync(false). half_sync(true) or a synchronize() call might block forever.

I haven't encountered any issues when running tests with half_sync(true). Could someone provide a simple example that illustrates how this deadlock may occur?
